# Build a DAG with minimal number of nodes with no incoming edges.

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I am looking for references/discussions/solutions on the next problem.
Given an undirected graph $G$, we can construct a directed acyclic graph $G'$ from $G$ by assigning direction to each edge. How to construct $G'$ with *minimal* number of nodes that have no input edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following. I assume that $G$ is a finite graph without loops and double edges.. Since the graph $G’$ is acyclic, each connected component of the graph $G$ have to have at least one node with no input edges. And this minimum is attained as follows. We shall deal with each connected component $C$  of the graph $G$ independently. Temporarily  remove some edges from $C$ to obtain a tree. Fix an arbitrary vertex of $C$ as a root and direct the edges of the tree in the direction from the root to leaves. Now enumerate the vertices of $C$ as follows. The root comes first, then come (in an arbitrary order) vertices with height $1$, then  come (in an arbitrary order) vertices with height $2$, and so forth. Now we restore the edges removed earlier, directing each of the removed edges from its lower vertex to its higher vertex.